# Duplicate entries when assigning custom id to Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, model, duplicates, eloquent

So i'm populating my database from a CRM and i'm trying to use the provided id for each item as my primary key (I feel like this will make things less complicated, but if this is bad practice please let me know). The problem is that when the table already has some data and i rerun the function, i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25930688' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but i would've expected Eloquent to check the row exists before trying to insert it. I've tried save, create, firstOrNew, firstOrCreate. They all return the same error. I've searched far and wide but I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure I'm searching for the right terms.

```
$listing = Property::create([
        'id' => $property['@attributes']['id'],
        'house_flat_number' => $property['address']['name'],
        'street_address_1' => $property['address']['street'],
        'street_address_2' => $property['address']['town'],
        'postcode' => $property['address']['postcode']
```

Comment: I don't think Laravel will check if the ID exists before inserting, you need to do that manually.

Comment: I would run a simple select query in whatever software you use to manage your db on your property table - 'select * from property where id = 25930688' and see if there is already a record, if so that is your issue.  Are you sure the ids you get from the CRM are unique? If so did you have existing data prior to this practice?

Comment: @Joshua – I figured this might be a solution. There was no existing data, and the CRM ids are unique. The problem was that I want to rerun the function only adding new properties, and each time it was adding all properties to the database, so it would go from 50, to 100, to 150

findOrNew + fill as suggested by jarek worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `findOrNew` + `fill` instead of `create` and you're good:

```php
$listing = Property::findOrNew($property['@attributes']['id'])
   ->fill([
     'id' => $property['@attributes']['id'],
     'house_flat_number' => $property['address']['name'],
     // ...
   ])->save();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I knew there had to be a function that took care of this. Seemed very un-laravel to not do it!